# We changed our privacy policy. Read この質問. (2021年9月時点)

Tags: サポート, 翻訳

2021年9月末にサイトが更新され、表題のような注記が画面上部に表示されました。
注記をクリックした際の[リンク先](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370216)を翻訳しました。
※下記のリンクは主に翻訳者によるものです

---

Updates to Privacy Policy (September 2021)

周知のことですがスタックオーバーフローは定期的にプライバシーポリシーを更新します。
今回も数か所のプライバシーポリシーを変更しました。
このポリシーはStack Overflow for Teamsや通常のQ&Aを含むスタック・ネットワーク全体におけるデータ収集、使用に影響します。

変更点を抜粋します。

- 個人情報保護方針(privacy notice)を、明確で、情勢に合致し、有用であることを維持するよう全面的に刷新して更新しました。
- 国際的なデータ転送の項目は、当社が国外へのデータ転送をPrivacy Shield([Google検索](https://www.google.com/search?q=privacy+shield))に依存しないことを反映して更新しました。
- 個人情報保護方針の構成を、明確で閲覧性を高めるため平易に書き換えました。
- 従来はTeamsの個人情報保護方針をFree, Basic, Businessの3項目に分割していましたが、これらを1項目に統合しました。
- 企業向けプライバシーポリシーが更新されました。
- [Collectives on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/06/23/collectives-stack-overflow/)のポリシーを新たに作成しました。
- このポリシーは製品広告による採用ブランディングもカバーします。
- 個人情報の関連法や情勢の変化を反映して、ポリシーを更新しました。
- [プライバシーポリシー](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/privacy-policy)はスタック・ネットワークいずれのサイトでもフッタに表示されています。そして(目立つように)サイトバナーで[この質問](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370216/updates-to-privacy-policy-september-2021)にリンクしています。